# How to get the user's first name from the Firebase composer UI?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create an experiment for push notifications using the Firebase composer UI. I want to send a push notification to users with their first name. But I can't find a way to get the user's first name from the composer UI. Is there a way to get the user's first name from the composer UI?

Example:
Hi {firstName}, we have a new feature for you.

I tried to use cloud functions to send the push notification. But the push notification API doesn't support A/B experiments. I also tried to use the composer UI to send the push notification. But I can't find a way to get the user's first name from the composer UI.